# Jsoup: get the html nearest tag before a tag

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I go a tag  name `<div id= "d1">`. But I want to know the tag, which is before this tag( the older bro/sis of this tag .anyone have an idea?

I am using java.

Comment: Define "before". Do you want sibling, or maybe ancestor? Or maybe it doesn't matter? Consider posting little larger example which will include element you are interested in.

Comment: Are you author of this edit suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12209180?

Comment: did i do something wrong???

Comment: oh i knew it now. The cache of browser.

Answer (score 0):

OP found an answer:

> I think i got my own answer. It's **lastElementSibling()**. I read it in this Jsoup API I hope this will help anyone like me now.